# How to adjust style of table cell border?

Tags: styles, border, cell, phpoffice

When I add a cell to a table, I can manipulate its thickness (borderBottomSize), its color (borderBottomColor) but not its style (dashed, dotted, longdashed, ...).

When I read the code, the PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Cell extends the PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Border.
And the border class has the attribute borderBottomStyle.
But how to configure that?

I also looked into the PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Line, there I can find some "dashStyles", but none of them are working...

My question: How to change style of border (from strong line to for example dotted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the style of the border by using the cell style property `borderStyle`. By default, it's set to `solid`, but you can use other values like `dashed`, `dotted`, `double`, etc. Sadly, this feature is not documented so I don't know all the available styles.

Don't forget to add a border size as well, otherwise no border will be rendered.

Example for a dotted cell:

```
$dottedCell = $tableRow->addCell($cellWidth, ['borderStyle' => 'dotted', 'borderSize' => 6]);
```

Comment: does there a way to make border raduis ?

Comment: No, Microsoft Word (and therefore also PhpWord) does not provide an option to set a border radius on tables

Comment: Hey, thank  your for your answer, so there's no way to do a radius box w a text inside !

Comment: While it's definitely not possible for tables that doesn't mean it's not possible at all. You might want to experiment with [textboxes](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_25_TextBox.php) or [shapes](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_31_Shape.php)

Comment: text boxes doest not support bg color, and shapes does not allow to write text inside the shape :/